# Add-remove class to Fixed element

Tags: jquery, html, addclass, sticky, removeclass

Trying to add and remove class to a jQuery sticky Fixed element `h2.sly-scroll-title3` *(Title 1)* when `#Label1` on the viewport. Means add class `.extraclass` to `h2.sly-scroll-title3` only when `#Label1` block on the viewport and remove class when its not on viewport.

HTML:

```
<div id="Label1">

<div class="bottom-label-post1">

<h2 class="sly-scroll-title3" >Title 1</h2> <!-- Scroll Element -->

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="list-label-widget-content">

Content 1

</div>

</div>

</div> <!-- End -->
```

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8g20ha5y/2/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sticky-end` event. The code will be like below -

```
$('h2.sly-scroll-title3').on('sticky-start', function() { $('h2.sly-scroll-title3').removeClass('extraclass'); });
$('h2.sly-scroll-title3').on('sticky-end', function() { $('h2.sly-scroll-title3').addClass('extraclass'); });
```

There are other events given below as per documentation-

```
$('#sticker').on('sticky-start', function() { console.log("Started"); });
$('#sticker').on('sticky-end', function() { console.log("Ended"); });
$('#sticker').on('sticky-update', function() { console.log("Update"); });
$('#sticker').on('sticky-bottom-reached', function() { console.log("Bottom reached"); });
$('#sticker').on('sticky-bottom-unreached', function() { console.log("Bottom unreached"); });
```

Comment: Please wait i will try.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more available events. Accept answer if works